# regular expression in perl for strings

Tags: regex, perl

Did anyone knows regular expression that validate the string against following criteria:

- Names can be between 1 and 255 characters long.
- Allowed characters are a–z, A–Z, 0–9, '_' (underscore), '-' (hyphen), and '.' (period).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regex: `/^[\w\-.]{1,255}$/`
Explanation: http://regex101.com/r/tR0lR8

Comment: You could shave off a backslash by reordering: `[\w.-]`

Comment: Now that you know the answer, learn what you can about regular expressions. I [wrote a turtorial](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/Regular_Expressions.doc) years ago as a tutorial for people in my group. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: @Zaid: Agreed, but it's good practice to escape it in order to avoid accidental (perhaps invalid) character ranges.

Comment: Thanks Davis for that useful document. But I get headache when it comes to solving regular expression. :)